# Run command after encoding completes in Adobe Media Encoder?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, adobe-media-encoder

I'm using Adobe Media Encoder CS6 (on Mac OS X Mountain Lion) to do a big encoding job, which will take about 6 hours.

I need to run a terminal command after my encoding is done. (The command is to upload the encoded files to a remote server.)

Is there any way I can trigger this command automatically when the encoding queue completes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be two parts to the question:

1. Is it possible (to launch a terminal command after encoding is done)?
2. How to do it?

---

1. Yes it is, via a script that would simulate "watch folder" behaviour:

   - watch for files in a specified folder
   - once a file is there, wait for it to becomes available (if it isn't outright): not being used by another process
   - once it's available, run a specified command (upload, etc.)
   - delete or move the file when done - otherwise the script will attempt to repeat the process

AME would have to be set to encode files into that "watched" folder, and the script running in infinite loop would pick it up from there.

2. Not sure if it can be done in BASH; certainly doable in perl.

Comment: Thank you 50-3 for the edit: part 2 of the answer is numbered "1" rather than "2" - any way to change that?